# capifony configuration for web deployment

Tags: symfony, deployment, capifony

I'm a freshman with capifony and need some help.
I have a webspace with a Serveradress , User and password. How must I configurate my deploy.rb to deploy my symfony application on my server?

The capifony documentation only comes up with these settings:

```
set   :application,   "My App"
set   :deploy_to,     "/var/www/my-app.com"
set   :domain,        "my-app.com"

set   :scm,           :git
set   :repository,    "ssh-gitrepo-domain.com:/path/to/repo.git"
```

But my webserver doesn't have a git repository , so i couldn't use capifony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use supported source control systems (git, svn, etc), then you can still deploy by disabling it. Change lines in your config to:

```
set :repository, "." 
set :scm, :none 
set :deploy_via, :copy
```

Comment: thx, my fault was, that i didn't configurate my ssh right. But now i get the following message on cap deploy:setup
failed: "sh -c 'mkdir -p /www/symfony /www/symfony/releases /www/symfony/shared'" on my-domain-name.com

Comment: with log:  mkdir: cannot create directory `/www.my-domain-name.com': Permission denied

Comment: i fixed it. I had to write: set :deploy_to,   "/home/username/www/symfony" instead of "/www/symfony" in my deploy.rb